# Fixing Beamer Turkish Translation

Tags: beamer, errors, translations

the document **translator-numbers-dictionary-Turkish.dict** contains a typo in the command

```
\providetranslation{Four}{D\"[o}rt}
```

which should be corrected as

```
\providetranslation{Four}{D\"{o}rt}
```

It is possible to fix this problem by using codes in preamble of my beamer **tex** document without fixing the typo in the **dic** file?

Thank you.

Comment: `\newtranslation{Four}{D\"{o}rt}` or possibly `\newtranslation[to=Turkish]{Four}{D\"{o}rt}` in the preamble I guess.

Comment: @cgnieder Thank you for the link, it seems that somebody has already reported. Btw, it did not work. I still get **! Too many }'s** error.

Comment: You didn't mention the error before but it makes sense: the dictionary is loaded, anyway. In that case you should fix the file and place it in your local tex tree until `translator` is fixed.